# Access to visual studio variables from Wix

Tags: visual-studio, wix

I have Visual Studio 2015 with Wix Extension 0.9.21.62588 and v4 toolset. According to the [document](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html) these are the project references and variables I can use.  In the pre build and post build steps I can access these fine

However I cant seem to access the other available options that a C++ project has access to example $(WindowsSdkDir), $(UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_x86) etc.  Is it possible, if not is there a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can do this by updating the $(DefineConstants) property in the project manually or through visual studio project properties > Build > Define preprocessor variables

You just need to use a semi-colon separated list of variable names-value pairs.

```
WindowsSdkDir=$(WindowsSdkDir);UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_x86=$(UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_x86)
```

In this format the $(VarName) references are the MSBuild properties. The name you want to use for your wix variables $(var.Name) can be anything you like.

Then in your wxs wix code you can access these values using $(var.WindowsSdkDir) or $(var.UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_x86)

Comment: Thanks for reply but when I set  WindowsSdkDir=$(WindowsSdkDir) in properties > Build > Define preprocessor variables, I still cant access the variable in Post Build Step (i.e. not in wix code itself) e.g. $(WindowsSdkDir)\bin\x64\signtool.exe"

Comment: Oh in that case it just sounds like your $(WindowsSdkDir) isn't defined properly. You can try using the "AfterBuild" target instead of the Post-build event but you'll need to edit your wixproj file. They are added by default but commented out. It may be that the properties are only defined during the build and the post-build event happens outside of that context. Everything available for the build should be available in the AfterBuild target.

Comment: Cant access it from there either.  However I also also cant access that variable from wix script itself.  Did you manage to get it to work